# Processing - How to tint only one image?

Tags: java, image, processing, tint

With my background set as an image, I want to play a transition effect using an image.

This is my code:

```
if (overStart == true) {
    overTransition = frameCount;
    overStart = false;
  }
  overTransitionEl = frameCount-overTransition;
  if (overTransitionEl<=120)
    tint(255, overTransitionEl*4.23);
  else {
    noTint();
  }
  pushMatrix();
  imageMode(CENTER);
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  image(gameOver, 0, 0);
  popMatrix();
```

Considering tint tints every image and not just the specific one (gameOver), the background (being an image) also fades in. Is there a workaround or do I have to leave out the transition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can call `noTint()` after drawing the image to revert to normal image mode before trying to draw any other images.

The example on the [reference for `noTint`](https://processing.org/reference/noTint_.html) demonstrates it pretty well.